# Apply Chi-Square to dataset which contains categorical variables

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy

My dataset has the following columns:

```
Voted? Political Category
Yes            Right
No             Left
Not Answered   Center
Yes            Right
Yes            Right
No             Right
```

I would need to calculate the chi square to see which category is mostly associated with people who voted. Both columns contain strings. How can I give each of the value a numeric representation in order to apply chi-square?

Comment: I like [pd.factorize()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.factorize.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.factorize` to encode your categorical variables:

```
df['nVoted?'] = pd.factorize(df['Voted?'])[0]
df['nCategory'] = pd.factorize(df['Political Category'])[0]
print(df)

# Output
         Voted? Political Category  nVoted?  nCategory
0           Yes              Right        0          0
1            No               Left        1          1
2  Not Answered             Center        2          2
3           Yes              Right        0          0
4           Yes              Right        0          0
5            No              Right        1          0
```

After that you can use [scipy.stats.chisquare](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chisquare.html)